# fall detection in Labview with quaternions

Tags: labview, quaternions

I have a wearable device that gives output in Quaternions which I can read serially via Labview. My task is to develop a threshold based fall detection system based on these values which I am not familiar with. The platform is Labview.

Could someone guide as to where I should start. FYI I don't have access to Accelerometer values.
Any help is appreciable

Here is a sample data I read from the device

id: 4 distance: 1048 q0: 646 q1: -232 q2: -119 q3: 717
id: 4 distance: 1067 q0: 645 q1: -232 q2: -80 q3: 722
id: 4 distance: 1109 q0: 645 q1: -232 q2: -81 q3: 722
id: 4 distance: 1036 q0: 645 q1: -232 q2: -80 q3: 722

Actually it has become more of a mathematical question now. I was able to find the Euler angles from the quaternions. I'm using the left hand or North East Down coordinates. The device is fixed on the shoe. I'm assuming forward and backward fall could be determined with yaw angle. Lateral fall with pitch. Is there a Combination of roll and pitch that could be used to find a fall?

Comment: This sounds like a maths question rather than a LabVIEW question - you could try the National Instruments LabVIEW forums though as there are probably people there with appropriate experience. A quick web search found me some relevant looking articles on this site: http://www.chrobotics.com/library/understanding-quaternions

Comment: You could also try searching / asking on robotics.stackexchange.com